# How to create Visual Studio DebuggerVisualizer for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debuggervisualizer

.NET allows you to create DebuggerVisualizers for data types in Visual Studio, I need to add the following attribute to types I want to visualize:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer("VisualizerTypeName", "ObjectSourceTypeName")]
```

Then it will add a little magnifying glass symbol next to expressions of that type in various debug windows, and when you click on the magnifying glass, it will pop up the specified visualizer.

I've been trying to find how to do the same thing for C++ types.  I'm aware of autoexp.dat and the VC2010Samples\C++\Debugging\EEaddin sample project, but those only seem to apply to the text output in the debugger window, not to forwarding data for a debug visualizer.

I assume it's going to be somehow related to autoexp.dat, but I can't find any information on marking a type for visualization.  How do I get the magnifying glass to pop up for arbitrary C++ types the way it does for char* types?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012 and later, it appears there is a new format for debug visualization, .natvis:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914(v=vs.110).aspx#BKMK_UIVisualizer

In Visual Studio 2010 and earlier, the best information I can find is that "stringview" is the only type visualization supported by autoexp.dat.  You can specify a string format to visualize a type as a string using the built in string visualizer, but no custom visualizers:

http://www.idigitalhouse.com/Blog/?p=83